# c++ opengl repeat

Tags: c++, opengl

I have tried to draw a part of a picture, but instead repeating the part of the picture, it has stretched the picture and it looked ugly.

How can I repeat picture instead of streching it.

The relevant part of the code:

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glColor3f(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[image]);
int repeat = (x2-x)/73;
glBegin(GL_QUADS); //create polygon
glTexCoord2f((part/3.f), 0.0f);glVertex2d(x, y);
glTexCoord2f(((part+1.f)/3.f)+repeat, 0.0f);glVertex2d(x2, y);
glTexCoord2f(((part+1.f)/3.f)+repeat, 1.0f);glVertex2d(x2, y2);
glTexCoord2f((part/3.f), 1.0f);glVertex2d(x, y2);
glEnd();
```

and the load of the texture:

```
texture[fNum] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
            (
            fName.c_str(),
            SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
            SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
            SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y 
            );
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

This is the fixed code after your help, but now there is another problem, I want to repeat only a specific part of the image.
Thank a lot!

fixed:
now I maked my own code to repeat that and it works:

```
float nx=x, nx2 = x+length;
float ny2 = y2+25.f;
if((x2-x)/length > 1)
{
    while(nx2 < x2)
    {
        if(nx2+length < x2)
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS); //create polygon
            glTexCoord2f((part/3.f), 0.0f);glVertex2d(nx, y);
            glTexCoord2f(((part+1.f)/3.f), 0.0f);glVertex2d(nx2, y);
            glTexCoord2f(((part+1.f)/3.f), 1.0f);glVertex2d(nx2, ny2);
            glTexCoord2f((part/3.f), 1.0f);glVertex2d(nx, ny2);
            glEnd();
            nx = nx2;
            nx2 += length;
        }
        else
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS); //create polygon
            glTexCoord2f((part/3.f), 0.0f);glVertex2d(nx, y);
            glTexCoord2f(((part+1.f)/3.f), 0.0f);glVertex2d(x2, y);
            glTexCoord2f(((part+1.f)/3.f), 1.0f);glVertex2d(x2, ny2);
            glTexCoord2f((part/3.f), 1.0f);glVertex2d(nx, ny2);
            glEnd();
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); //create polygon
    glTexCoord2f((part/3.f), 0.0f);glVertex2d(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(((part+1.f)/3.f), 0.0f);glVertex2d(x2, y);
    glTexCoord2f(((part+1.f)/3.f), 1.0f);glVertex2d(x2, ny2);
    glTexCoord2f((part/3.f), 1.0f);glVertex2d(x, ny2);
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of code you used.

Comment: alright, I added it now.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't repeat anything, it's just one quad.

Comment: Yes, I asked how  to do that. I have tried and didn't success.

Comment: Then you should have posted the code that _doesn't_ work.

Comment: Who cares if it's silly code. If someone needs it to give you a decent answer, then post it. Otherwise they can just guess.

Comment: I added now the fixed code, after your help, but there is another problem now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when mapping texture using `glTexCoord2f(x, y)` use x > 1.0 to repeat it in x direction and same for y.
If you use `glTexCoord2f(2.5, 3.0);` then image will be repeated 2 times completely plus half of its width in x-direction and 3 times in y-direction.

Comment: It drew some part of it transparent.

Answer (score 2):

You need texture coordinates greater than 1.0 (2.0 means twice, 3.0 means thrice, etc...) and you need to set the specific states as well:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: Actualy, there is another problem now, it maked a border, it wasn't there before.. and I want the repeat only about specific part.

Comment: Can you describe the border or upload a screenshot ?